# Spark : aggregated sum is not correct

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm using Spark to aggregate the amounts that are stored in parquets.
The parquet is in this format :

```
Amount | User
20     | Tim
```

and the parquets are in following two directories :

```
/dev/store1
/dev/store2
```

This is what I tried :

```
Dataset<MyModel> union_ds = null;
for (String path : paths) {
    Dataset<MyModel> ds = sparkSession.read().schema(mySchema).parquet(path).as(myEncoder);
    if (union_ds == null) {
        union_ds = ds;
    } else {
        union_ds = union_ds.union(ds);
    }
}
Double totalAmount = union_ds.agg(sum("Amount")).collectAsList().get(0).getDouble(0);
```

But for some reason it's not working, there is no error thrown but I got the total amount number not correct, I don't know why. Is there any problem with the below code ? Is there any other way to aggregate the sum ?

Comment: You can directly read multiple files as `sparkSession.read().schema(mySchema).parquet("path1, path2, path3..")` and you don't have to perform union.

Comment: @koiralo Hi, no it does not allow me to do so, it tells me to give a basePath. From what I understand I can only do like what you said if the path are paths of parquet, not their directory

Comment: but my question is rather if the sum function is correctly used in my case ?

Comment: Might be a stupid idea, but did you check your `union_ds` before summing, does it get "concatenated" correctly, and number of rows is fine?

Comment: @Rayan Ral hi how could I check this ? My job is running on Spark node so I tried to use .show() but it shows nothing in web console. I am new to Spark

Comment: `.show()` actually collects data on the driver, so it should work fine. Other way, if your data is very big, and one datasets can fit on a driver, you can try collecting it before union (something like `print(ds.collectAsList().length())`)